# How to add hidden user

Tags: macos, administrator

How do I add a hidden administrator user to my Mac if possible?
I don't want it to show up on the login screen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this hint from [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998). There are distinct differences between Yosemite and all earlier OS X versions.

I'll copy/paste the Yosemite commands here so as not to offend the 'no solitary links in answers' demigods.

***Quoth Apple Support:***

**Hide a user account in OS X Yosemite**

You can prevent a user account from appearing in the login window in OS X Yosemite by using these steps:

1. Log in as an admin user.
2. Use this Terminal command, substituting the short account name name of the user you wish to hide for “hiddenuser”:

   ```
   sudo dscl . create /Users/hiddenuser IsHidden 1
   ```

If you later want to show the hidden user, set the user’s `IsHidden` attribute to 0 like this:

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/hiddenuser IsHidden 0
```

**Additional Options**

You can also move the hidden user's home directory to a place not visible from the Finder, and remove the hidden user's Public Folder share point.

The following command moves the home directory of "hiddenuser" to /var, a hidden directory:

```
sudo mv /Users/hiddenuser /var/hiddenuser
```

The following command updates the user record of "hiddenuser" with the new home directory path in /var:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser NFSHomeDirectory /var/hiddenuser
```

The following command removes the Public Folder share point for the user with the long name "Hidden User”:

```
sudo dscl . -delete "/SharePoints/Hidden User's Public Folder"
```

**Logging in to this hidden account**

To access this hidden admin account from the login screen, press the down arrow to select any user (make sure the password entry box is not open), then press <kbd>Opt-Return</kbd>.

This will bring up the blank name and password fields, allowing you to sign into to the hidden admin account.

**Display all users (including hidden)**

Remember that a hidden user can still be found, do not use this as a security measure. To show a list of all possible users, use `dscacheutil`

```
dscacheutil -q user
```

or to display all users in the 'Users' group (5**)

```
dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: This is the correct OS X way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your additions. They greatly add to the utility of the answer.

Comment: With FileVault on, the login screen cannot just show name/password inputs, see [this reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/7jrwjx/hide_all_users_at_login_screen/dr8rx7o/).